# About some materials on GCC, Linux

Tags: gcc, linker

I am a newbie in GCC and Linux. I have been using Visual Studio for almost all course projects, so when switching to GCC and Linux, I feel so suffering, especially when compiling some projects and it complains for some errors.

I think I should do something to get rid of this annoying situation. But I don't know how to get some materials, maybe on linkers, on GCC flags, on libraries, could somebody kind enough pointing out what should I study or pay attention?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GCC user manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.4/gcc/) has to be your first reference..and you can get its online/pdf versions [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/)..

Answer (score 0):

There is lots of online documentation for the GNU tools:

- [Online GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/)
- [Online LD documentation](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/)
- [Online GLIBC documentation](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Linux manpages and infopages are one of the most important resources, and one of the most confusing for Windows users (SCNR: because it is fairly good, complete and useful documentation that comes for free and pre-installed on the system). You can reach them via the command-line `man` and `info` commands combined with the program, e.g.

```
man gcc
man fopen
info gcc
```

Sometimes, you need to install an extra -doc package for the man or the info pages. The gcc manual, for example, is available as an info page.

The second thing you need to learn is to look at the documentation of the right tool. Visual Studio performed the jobs of at least a dozen UNIX programs, so read the motivation section of the documentation and try to understand what program does what job. That is: You usually need an editor (vim), a compiler (gcc), a linker (ld), and archive indexer (ranlib) and a debugger (gdb) in your toolchain under Linux, even though you needn't call all of these by hand.

In addition, you should know about the autotools (`autoconf` and `automake`) and `libtool` because they make your job a *lot* easier.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what is painful for you. Is it the understanding of Linux system libraries, or is it just that it is painful to develop software on Linux, because you didn't caught how experimented Linux developers work, on a day by day or even minute by minute basis?